# How to use proxy by curl_init?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.php.net/';
$proxy = '104.41.154.213:8118';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);




if (preg_match('<body class="home ">', $data)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

It's working when I am stopped using the proxy but not working on any proxy. Can anyone please help me where is the problem?

Comment: What's your proxy type?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [proxytype](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.html) for your curl.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,xxxxxxx);
```

You also can debug the curl error, with

```
if($data === false)
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
```